# How to do search function for bus

Tags: c, queue

I want to do a search function for this program at `void search(void);`.

In this function, the user will enter the information at `void arrive(void);`.

After that, I going to scan the char that user typed, which is `bus_num[20]`, and the program is going to show the `bus_type` and `capacity`. Can somebody teach me how to do this ?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void arrive(void);
void leave(void);
void search(void);
void print(void);
void length(void);
int count;

struct bus{
    char bus_num[20];
    char bus_type[20];
    int capacity;
    struct bus *next;
}*ptr, *temp, *front, *rear;

void main()
{
    temp = NULL;
    rear = NULL;
    front = NULL;
    int option = 0;


    while (option != 6)
    {
        printf("\n\n*****menu driven*****\n");
        printf("\n\t 1.Arrive");
        printf("\n\t 2.Leave");
        printf("\n\t 3.Search");
        printf("\n\t 4.Print");
        printf("\n\t 5.Length");
        printf("\n\t 6.Exit");
        printf("\n\nSelect a option\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch (option)
        {
        case 1: arrive();break;
        case 2:leave();break;
        case 3:search();break;
        case 4:print();break;
        case 5:length();break;
        case 6:break;
        default: printf("\nInvalid Option\n");
        }
        getch();

    }
    getch();
}
void arrive(void)
{
    temp = (struct bus*)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct bus));
    printf("\nPlease Enter The Bus Registeration Number :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &temp->bus_num);
    printf("\nPlease Enter The Bus Type :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &temp->bus_type);
    printf("\nPlease Enter The Bus Capacity :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &temp->capacity);
    count++;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
    {
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = rear->next;


}


void leave(void)
{
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThere are empty queue\n");
        return;
    }
    if (front == rear&&front != NULL)
    {
        ptr = front;
        printf("%s leaves the queue", &ptr->bus_num);
        front = rear = NULL;
        free(ptr);
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = front;
        printf("%s leaves", &ptr->bus_num);
        front = front->next;
        free(ptr);
    }
    count--;
}

void print(void)
{
    if (front == NULL&&rear == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThere are no any Queue\n");
        return;
    }
    ptr = front;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\t", ptr->bus_num);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void length(void)
{
    printf("\n Queue size is %d", count);
}

void search(void)
{

}
```